# How to put data from various tables into separate lists via one request

Tags: scala, doobie

For instance, I have some entity. Each entity has some attributes. DB looks something about:

```
 entity                entity_attribute
╔════╦════════╗       ╔════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ name   ║       ║ id ║ entity_id  ║ attribute ║
╠════╬════════╣       ╠════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1  ║  One   ║       ║ 1  ║ 1          ║ "aaa"     ║ 
║ 2  ║  Two   ║       ║ 2  ║ 1          ║ "bbb"     ║
║ 3  ║  Three ║       ║ 3  ║ 1          ║ "ccc"     ║
╚════╩════════╝       ║ 4  ║ 1          ║ "ddd"     ║
                      ║ 5  ║ 2          ║ "aa"      ║
                      ║ 6  ║ 2          ║ "bb"      ║
                      ╚════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

My models looks like this:

```
case class Entity(id: Long, name: String)

case class Entityattribute(id: Long, entityId: Long, attribute: String)
```

And I am trying to get entitites with attributes(**Important: No join**) via `doobie`:

```
(for {
      entitites <- sql"select id, name from entity"query[Entity].to[List]
      attributes <- (sql"select id, entity_id, attribute from entity_attribute where " ++ 
                    Fragments.in(
                      fr"entity_id", 
                      NonEmptyList.fromListUnsafe(entities.map(_.id)))   //Unsafe, just example
                    ).query[EntityAttribute].to[List]
      } yield entitites ++ attributes).transact(xa)
```

The result is one `List[Product]`:

```
List(
  Entity(1, One),
  Entity(2, Two),
  Entity(3, Three),
  EntityAttribute(1,1,"aaa"),
  EntityAttribute(2,1,"bbb"),
  EntityAttribute(3,1,"ccc"),
  EntityAttribute(4,1,"ddd"),
  EntityAttribute(5,2,"aa"),
  EntityAttribute(6,2,"bb")
)
```

How to modify doobie request to get result into two separate `List[Entity]` and `List[EntityAttribute]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists in Scala are homogeneous, that means compiler will try to find upper bound for types of all objects in the list.

For your case, upper bound for `Entity` and `EntityAttribute` is `Product`.

What you can do to preserve original types is just returning a tuple containing two lists: `List[Entity]` and `List[EntityAttribute]`.

```
} yield (entitites, attributes)).transact(xa)
```

Then you could retrieve lists by just pattern matching on a tuple:

```
result.map {
   case (entities, attributes) => /* do something */
}
```